# google visualization query can't run maximum and sum query

Tags: javascript, google-visualization, google-fusion-tables

I'm trying to get the data from my fusion tables. when I use SELECT query the data show successfull. but when I'm using SUM and MAXIMUM query the firebug show error :
 "SyntaxError: syntax error
Error 500 (There's a p"

when i test my query from [fusion query](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/fusiontables/v1/fusiontables.query.sql) the query works.

when i search based from firebug error, it's because i'm not specify the script tag to script type="text/javascript" .

but i think it's not actualy the error i get, because yesterday my code works. and today i don't know why my code doesn't works.

Can anybody help me? thanks for any help.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript"> 
   // Fusion Table data ID
   var FT_TableID = '1j1AG2s_IgNBQmm0QP9yYGHFg2_rNSZoEH4ee80In';
   var FT_TableIDSP = '1O5aIPnHBCimWsYg0gOXIeRH6eL-6byD95Nd2pdXR';
   google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart', 'table', 'geomap']});
   
   function getKP() {
    // set the query using the parameters
    var FT_Query_KP = "SELECT 'Kelompok Penanam', count() FROM "+FT_TableID+" GROUP by 'Kelompok Penanam' ORDER by 'idPenanam'";
    //var FT_Query_KP = "SELECT SUM('Tinggi Pohon') FROM 1O5aIPnHBCimWsYg0gOXIeRH6eL-6byD95Nd2pdXR";
    //var FT_Query_KP = "SELECT MAXIMUM('Tinggi Pohon') FROM 1O5aIPnHBCimWsYg0gOXIeRH6eL-6byD95Nd2pdXR";
    var queryText = encodeURIComponent(FT_Query_KP);
    var query = new google.visualization.Query('http://www.google.com/fusiontables/gvizdata?tq='  + queryText);
    //set the callback function
    query.send(KP);
   }
   // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
   function KP(response) {
    if (!response) {
     alert('no response');
     return;
    }
    if (response.isError()) {
     alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
     return;
    } 
    var KPname = response.getDataTable().getValue(0,0);
   
    document.getElementById('dropdownKP').innerHTML = KPname;
   }
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   getKP();
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="dropdownKP"></div> 
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It is displaying TUK for me, is that the expected result?

Comment: Yes, it's right. but if you change to uncomment the SUM or MAXIMUM query and comment the SELECT query the code show alert like "responce errorr". can you help me how to fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Rod and Juvian, I change code from google visualization query to google fusion v1 query from this [link](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/samples/basic_jsonp_request)

Answer (score 0):

We've identified a problem in the code for summaries with no second column in the projection; pie charts are the only ones that allow that, so it slipped past us. We are working on a fix and will update this question when it's available.

That said, the pie charts resulting from such queries wouldn't be too useful because they only have a single value.

Comment: Yes, the code will summaries only one column if using SUM or MAXIMUM query, if this because there is any update from Google Fusion API v1 to V2 or the JSAPI has change? can you help me to fix it because in november 18 the code works. Thanks Rod.

Comment: There was a change on our side in the handling of Gviz queries. This does not affect the regular Fusion Tables API. You can run this query using the V1 or V2 API, and then create your own data table for the charts. It's when using this directly as a visualization data source that you will see the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Rod. are there any other solution for my problem Rod?

Comment: are you and your Google Fusion Table Team have a desire to change the GVIZ works like before or your team have any other solution to fix my problem Rod? I'm really appreciate you and your team works and thankyou for your willingness to reply...